# Drawable with bitmap element showing on phone, but not tablet

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable

I have created a **bg.xml** in `res/drawable-hdpi` as well as in `drawable-xhdpi` with following element:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/mainbg"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:dither="true" />
```

This works fine on my Samsung S3. However on my Nexus 7 (v2) the background doesn't show up. 
The src file is added to the xhpdi-folder so it is there. 
Also added

```
   < supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true">
```

What could the issue be?

Comment: create new folder with name drawable-sw720dp or drawable-sw600dp & place image in that folder & try once...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - the xml-file had differences, thats the reason. Silly. Thanks for help.